# How to execute a CronJob using Laravel and Forge

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I need to execute a CronJob in forge Laravel, but when I set the time to daily this job don't run at midnight at Forge, but when I set the time in forge to everyMinute, it works.

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use App\Models\User;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{

    protected $commands = [
        \App\Console\Commands\Inspire::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function() {
            $users = User::all();

            foreach($users as $user) {
                if($user->remaining_days == 0 && $user->user_level != 4)
                    $user->user_level = 0;
                else
                    $user->remaining_days = $user->remaining_days - 1;

                $user->save();
            }
        })->daily();

    }

    protected function commands()
    {
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`->dailyAt()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling#defining-schedules) clause instead of `->daily()`:

```
->dailyAt('12:00');
```

If you want to run it at midnight, I guess you should also check server's timezone to make sure you're passing right time into `->dailyAt()`.